Sending Emails from Gmail to Exchange Mail in ASP.NET Core MVC: How Can I Achieve This?
I've encountered a perplexing issue with my ASP.NET Core MVC project. Within my application, I've integrated a contact form feature to facilitate user inquiries and feedback submissions. The objective is to route these submissions from my personal Gmail account to my professional Exchange email address. However, despite successfully dispatching emails from Gmail, I'm confronted with an intriguing dilemma: none of these emails are reaching my Exchange mailbox.
To address this challenge, I've conducted several troubleshooting steps. I've experimented with different SMTP ports, including the commonly used 465 and 587. Furthermore, I've conducted test transmissions by sending emails from Gmail to alternative email providers like Yandex. Curiously, the problem persists regardless of the recipient's email domain. Despite Gmail indicating successful transmissions, none of these emails are visible in my Exchange mailbox within Outlook.
Seeking assistance from the community, I'm hopeful that someone might offer insights or solutions to resolve this issue. If anyone has encountered similar challenges or possesses expertise in troubleshooting email delivery discrepancies between Gmail and Exchange, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
Thank you sincerely for any assistance you can provide.


Do not post images of code. Post code (text formatted as code).

Also: this seems very '90s style. Why not write all this to a database and maybe use some sort of notification system?

Meanwhile: afaik gmail has retired user/password auth. Which one of the newer options are you using?

i already all of them to a database but i need send email. I watched a video about sending email. So that's why it seems like 90's

As @Fildor asked already do you have set up an AppPassword for the gmail account. A normal password is not sufficient for unattended usage anymore. And when you think you have valid App Credentials have you checked the inbox of the gmail account for bounce mails when the problem arises only after the smtp server has received and forwarded the mail?

have you checked mail server logs? also check the junk mail. have you tried testing sending email to the other account to exchange server. try to send email from different account other then Gmail and test is it reaching out to the exchange server or not. you could try checking exchange server delivery reports: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/track-messages-with-delivery-reports?view=exchserver-2019

Most likely they are ending up in your Spam folder on your Exchange account.
